# LOOK BACK function in LSTM by Keras

Tags: python, numpy, keras, deep-learning

I have a table of 6 (can be increased to 8) features and one specific column of the target. If I want to design a recurrent neural network or LSTM using keras I should define a function that represents the idea of taking look at the last time step to estimate the next time step. I currently used this code but I think something do not go right.

```
# convert an array of values into a dataset matrix
def create_dataset(dataset, look_back=1):
    dataX, dataY = [], []
    for i in range(len(dataset)-look_back-1):
        a = dataset[i:(i+look_back), 0]
        dataX.append(a)
        dataY.append(dataset[i + look_back, 0])
    return numpy.array(dataX), numpy.array(dataY)
```

What should I do when I have 6 or more columns of features and 1 column of a target. All efforts will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

make sure you are passing the numpy array of shape :- (no. of rows, 1)
as first argument of the function
and you will be good

```
import numpy as np
listing = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0,0,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1])
listing = listing.reshape(20,1)
def create_dataset(dataset, look_back=5):
    dataX, dataY = [], []
    for i in range(len(dataset)-look_back-1):
        a = dataset[i:(i+look_back), 0]
        dataX.append(a)
        dataY.append(dataset[i + look_back, 0])
    return np.array(dataX), np.array(dataY)
listing2,listing3 = create_dataset(listing)
```